# Oh-my-zsh error when running `source .zshrc`

Tags: command-line-interface, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I'm having troubles running `youtube-dl` and I get the error `zsh: command not found: youtube-dl` and as I was trying to figure it out.

So I tried to run `source ~/.zshrc` and I get the error `/Users/ynom/.zshrc:source:67: no such file or directory: /oh-my-zsh.sh`

In `.zshrc` I have the line `source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh` so I tried `echo $ZSH` and I get a blank line as a return.

I'm sorry I can't describe this problem better, but I'm very confused about the causes and how to trouble shoot this.

Answer (score 2):

The `$ZSH` var is probably not yet set.

Add the following to `.zshrc`;

```
export ZSH=/Users/yangnom/.oh-my-zsh
```

Now, we can `source` the file;

```
source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
```